# qt-designer project that deployed in win-10 doesn't work in win-7

Tags: qt, deployment, windows-7, qt-designer

I created an application using Qt and compiled with Visual Studio 2017 in win 10. I deployed this project and it works well in win 10. But when I run the exe file in win7, It doesn't work and I receive an error message like this:

> The program can't start because MSVCP140.dll is missing from your
>   computer...

I should mention that the MSVCP140.dll already exists on that computer. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/register-dll-file-windows) might hold the answer, [this one](https://ss64.com/nt/regsvr32.html) has an example

**Register dll file**

To register a dll or ocx file, open a command prompt windows as an administrator, type the following and hit Enter:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO360.DLL"
```

you migt add a "/s" to re-register, being:

```
regsvr32 /s "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO360.DLL"
```

Comment: thank you. I registered dll such as you mentioned. But the problem still remains.